# MVC3 Ajax ActionLink to call javascript function when completed with TempData

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been trying to get a notification to show when a user invokes an action in my controller. This works fine for most of my actions, however I use an `Ajax.ActionLink` to delete my items and therefore the page isn't refreshed and the javascript function isn't called and therefore the notification doesn't show.

In my `_Layout` page I have the notification system as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Used to display and close the system notifications
    $(document).ready(function notify() {
        $("#NotificationBox").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        if ($("#NotificationAutoHide").val() == "true") {
            $("#NotificationBox").delay(5000).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="NotificationDiv">
    @if (TempData["Notification"] != null)
    { 
        @Html.Hidden("NotificationAutoHide", TempData["NotificationAutoHide"])
        <div id="NotificationBox" class="@TempData["NotificationCSS"]" style="display: none">
             @TempData["Notification"]
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

In my `Index` view (which uses the layout page) I have the `Ajax ActionLink` that calls my `Delete` action in my controller, which also populates the required `TempData` properties.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MyController",
    new { id = item.UserID },
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "Delete",
        OnBegin = "JSONDeleteFile_OnBegin",
        OnComplete = "notify"
    },
    new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

I thought by adding the call to the `notify` function from the `OnComplete` options in the `ActionLink` then everything would work, but unfortunatly this doesn't seem to work.

I have seen some examples that suggest sending the `TempData` back through a `JsonResult` from my conntroller, however I'm not sure how to tie that into my existing code. (my controller already returns a JsonResult object for other uses)

Could anyone help me get the `TempData` back from the Ajax call and execute my notification system?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `notify` function is publicly visible so that you can invoke it from the AJAX success callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notify() {
        $("#NotificationBox").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        if ($("#NotificationAutoHide").val() == "true") {
            $("#NotificationBox").delay(5000).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(notify);
</script>
```

The way you have declared the `notify` function makes it impossible to invoke this function from an outside scope:

```
$(document).ready(function notify() { ... });
```

I don't even know if this is valid javascript syntax. Never seen someone using it.

Comment: I actually got this code from an example on the web, but I have seen it used in a few examples. However I'm pretty new to all of this so I have no idea what is a good practice or not! I will update my code later to try this. Do you have any idea how to populate the TempData with values from my Json result, or better still, the proper way to do this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since TempData is a Server Side Code, I don't think it's possible. You should return this information by JsonResult.

example:

```
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
  //do stuff
  return Json(new {param1 = "what you need", param2 = "more info"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Won't this mean i would have to return json from all of my controller methods? I don't know if thats possible as the other methods need to return views.

Comment: No, just the Delete Action. The others you'll continue return Views

Comment: In that case, it is possible to add values to the TempData from a Json return? Otherwise I will have to put the values somewhere else and modify my notification system to read from TempData and if that's null, then these other variables. As you can probablt tell I'm pretty new to all this! Thanks.

Comment: Since you are posting with Ajax, your tempdata will be empty when the action return the Json. You'll have to return the data you want by JsonResult or you'll have to reload your page (but you'll miss the Ajax benefit)

Comment: take a look at this samples and see if helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124541/Working-on-JSON-objects-in-jQuery-and-MVC   http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=399

Comment: Looks like I will have to use TempData for my non-Ajax posts and then use Json data when I use Ajax. I was hoping to have an common solution, but if this is the way it needs to be done, then I will have to try and figure it out! Thanks.